# Should Javascript still be "hidden" in HTML comment tags?

Tags: javascript, notation

I have recently inherited some web code and found that all the Java Script scripts are contained within HTML comment tags

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"><!--
    function ValidateForm() { ... }//-->
```

As I understand it, this method prevented older, non-supported, browsers from interpreting your Java Script. However this is not something I was ever taught to do, and I wonder if this is now considered to be unnecessary, or is this still a common practice? If so, why?

---

**Update**: Thanks to kennebec for your advice to leave them in, which I have done for now, and thanks to Emmett also: I'll be sure to leave them out of any future code I write!

Comment: In your situation I would leave the comment tags on any inherited code that you have not thoroughly checked-look for other 'legacy' code use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html:

> Do not use the `<!-- //-->` hack with
>   scripts. It was intended to prevent
>   scripts from showing up as text on the
>   first generation browsers Netscape 1
>   and Mosaic. It has not been necessary
>   for many years. `<!-- //-->` is supposed
>   to signal an HTML comment. Comments
>   should be ignored, not compiled and
>   executed. Also, HTML comments are not
>   to include --, so a script that
>   decrements has an HTML error.

Comment: It's funny to read about HTML best practices in a document that doesn't even have a DOCTYPE `;-P`

Answer (score 2):

It is because of XHTML validator. HTML comments around js code should used outside  tag. The validator is supposed to look at your html, not your js.

I strongly recommended this text
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/properly_using_css_and_javascript_in_xhtml_documents 
where is everything about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

My website is XHTML 1.1, which is XML.

My JavaScript is wrapped in
`//<![CDATA[`  and `//]]>`, if there is an XML entity (such as '&', '<', or '>') in the code.

Comment: '&', '<', and '>' are not entities.  They are special characters that can be escaped using entity references.

Comment: @Mike: You know what I meant.  I just didn't know what word to use.  :-P

Comment: yep.  Not disagreeing, just clarifying terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `<!--` could cause a script to fail when there is a `</script` as part of the program text inside the `<!-- ... -->`.

For example,

```
<script><!--
function containsScriptEndTag(s) {
  return s.indexOf('</script>') >= 0;
}
//-->
</script>
```

will parse differently without the `<!-- ... -->`.

So go ahead and remove them, but check first.

Btw, inside `script` elements, they're not called "comments", they're called "escaping text spans".
From http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/syntax.html#syntax-escape

> An escaping text span is a span of
>   text that starts with an escaping text
>   span start that is not itself in an
>   escaping text span, and ends at the
>   next escaping text span end. There
>   cannot be any character references
>   inside an escaping text span —
>   sequences of characters that would
>   look like character references do not
>   have special meaning.
>
> An escaping text span start is a part
>   of text that consists of the four
>   character sequence "
>
> An escaping text span end is a part of
>   text that consists of the three
>   character sequence "-->" (U+002D
>   HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS,
>   U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN) whose U+003E
>   GREATER-THAN SIGN (>).
>
> An escaping text span start may share
>   its U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS characters
>   with its corresponding escaping text
>   span end.

Comment: This is a great point but this: "An escaping text span is a span of text that starts with an escaping text span start that is not itself in an escaping text span, and ends at the next escaping text span end." is one of the most horrible sentences I have ever read, lol.

Comment: @Andy F, I agree and I wish the HTML5 spec would have used the usual BNF grammars for some of these normative sections so they could use looser non-normative explanatory language, but they're not going to revamp the authoring conventions this late in the game.